# How to merge two pages

Tags: adminmenu

I have on admin panel in menu section for example

```
 "review & rating"
     ->"customer review"
           -> "pending review"
           -> "all review"
```

that is "customer review" has two sub-links "pending review" & "all review"

Now when i click on "customer review" it will show "pending review" page .

I want to merge or say append the contents of "all review" on "pending review" page.So that when i click on "customer review" it will show "pending review" page which will show both the pages contents.

Help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Normally it would be by just adding the second grid block in the adminhtml layout XML but the review grid works a bit differently.

The `all reviews` page translates to `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_ReviewController::indexAction`, there the grid block is added via

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/review_main'));
```

Now if you scroll down to the `pendingAction` it basically does the same except also setting a flag for `pending` reviews

```
    Mage::register('usePendingFilter', true);
```

Added the block twice, one before and one after the flag wouldn't work either since the blocks aren't directly rendered to html so they would both use the flag.

Basically, if you want to do this you'll have to rebuild the default adminhtml review controller and grid blocks to fit your needs

Comment: Then also if there any other way of doing this without changing default structure..I need to do it any how..I have tried a lot but not getting any output